Ban on Generative AI
I often use AI to help reword and reformat my questions. As someone with ADHD often my questions go in circles or tangents. Is this new rule permanent? How will it address issues such as language barriers and learning disabilities for the asking of questions?
I completely understand the ban on providing AI generated answers as they can be inaccurate, incomplete etc.
Can someone from the Stack Overflow team clarify this?

Regarding "language barriers": From what I understand generative AI models aren't built specifically for the purpose of translations, so although they might allow one to translate things their accuracy is not guaranteed. If users are using other dedicated models for translation (they do exist) and those are being mistaken as generative AI that would be a topic the community might want to discuss.

Note that the ban focuses on real "generative" AI, rewriting tools that only change wording, not meaning, such as Grammarly, are generally considered exempt

Word of caution. While Grammarly used to only correct grammar using non generative AI, they are now also offering generative AI tools which do rewrite the content with AI and which can be detected as being AI generated or assisted.

@Cerbrus Because sooner or later someone will use that Grammarly AI tool and then claim that they through everything from Grammarly is allowed.

@DalijaPrasnikar I actually realized that the rewrite tool is directly available in the plugin... Yikes.

"I completely understand the ban on providing AI generated answers as they can be inaccurate, incomplete etc." - then also ban human answers :) no its because there is zero thought or experience behind them, so the chance of the answer being inaccurate, incomplete, etc. is unnecessarily high. This is, at the time of writing, a quality-driven site and not a quantity-driven one. Lord knows how long that is going to last though.

If you don't think you are able to ask a question on SO for whatever disability reason you might have, then how exactly would it be easier to create an AI prompt to a chat bot and have it "proof read" your question, then filter out the bot response? In comparison, that is much harder to do and get right, than asking a question on SO in the first place.
Given that there are tons of people willing to edit your question into shape, just ask it? They might even edit your question to improve it whether you like it or not.

Considering ADHD is basically a global flag for "Needs Focus" it's very likely a question written by someone with it would be closed with a similar flag.  I personally have ADHD and have spent 2 days doing a Mark Twain ("writing is easy, just cross out all the wrong words") activity on a question to make sure it doesn't get immediately deleted.

Case in point - the point of the above is that it's unlikely "let editors fix it in post" would do much to help, since a standard ADHD influenced question will get closed before getting a chance, even if an editor could save it.

That said, GenAI probably isn't the answer either, since someone with ADHD is also less likely to be able to catch anything the GenAI hallucinates into the question.

@DanielF And yet you are writing fully coherent comments in flawless English here. So perhaps you too are exaggerating the impact of your diagnosis?

It just took me 3 comments over 10 minutes to make a point >.<  I don't have problems expressing myself in english, I have problems with stopping expressing myself.

I didn't ask for any accomodation and in fact stated that AI wasn't the answer for my particular issue.  I simply said that throwing oneself at the mercy of the edit queue isn't an option for folks with ADHD.  I'm not sure how that's being construed into "boo hoo I'm a victim" other than as reflex against any accomodation at all.

@DanielF Different people will have different levels of difficulty posting questions, no matter if the reason is ADHD, dyslectics or because they are just not native English. All of these at individual degrees, there's no such thing as a general diagnosis. We are constantly prompting non-native English to post on SO, at the mercy of the edit queue. While they might in fact have a much harder time here than a native English with ADHD. There's different degrees of everything.

Anyway, we seem to agree that Gen AI is not the best solution to the problem. There are non-AI spelling/grammar checking tools that might be far more helpful.
